# Is this statement true for an arbitrary real function? If $\int_{a}^{b} f^2(x) = 0$ then $f(x) = 0$.

Tags: integration

Is this statement true for arbitrary real functions? If so, how to prove it?

> If $\int_{a}^{b} f^2(x) = 0$ then $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: No take the dirac delta function

Comment: No. take $f(x)=0$ for $x<1$ and $f(1)=1$. However for continuous functions your statement is true.

Comment: dirac function isn't a real function as title asks but not body...)

Comment: @TsemoAristide: The Dirac delta function  is not a function but a distribution.

Comment: @SmileyCraft But the integrand is the *square* of $f$ so if $f$ odd square is even.

Comment: This is true if you add the condition that $f$ be continuous.

Comment: In general we use the suffix $f=0\quad\mu\text{.p.p}$ or $\mu.\text{a.e}$ meaning "presque partout"="almost everywhere" according to measure $\mu$, in our case this is simply everywhere except on a set of Lebesgue measure $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is false in general: take a function that equals $1$ on some point, and $0$ everywhere else.

For continuous functions it is true.

**Proof:** suppose $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and *not identically zero*. Let $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_0)\neq 0$, then $f(x_0)^2 > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^2$ is also continuous so there exists an interval with non-empty interior containing $x_0$ where $f(x)^2 > \eta$ where $\eta = f(x_0)^2/2$. Let $\ell > 0$ be the length of this interval. By breaking the interval into three pieces, and noticing that $f(x)^2\geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ one obtains that $\int_a^b f^2 \geq \ell \cdot \eta > 0$. In particular, $\int_a^b f^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: Can you give me an example of where this statement can be true?

Comment: @user637244 take $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for all $0<x\leq 1$

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not true. For example you can pick $f(x)=0$ except for a finite set of points for which you can assign arbitrary nonzero values. Then the integral of $f^2$ is still $0$. Intuitively speaking, the integral measures the area behind the graph of the function, and modifying a finite set of points of the graph does not modify the area.

Comment: It is true, however, if you identify such functions in the usual way.

Comment: @Klaus After you've identified functions that differ only on a set of measure zero, they are not functions anymore (contrary to the popular abuse of language).

Comment: Can you give me an example of where this statement can be true?

Comment: @user637244 Do you mean an example in which your conjecture is true, or an specific example of my argument?

Comment: @lisyarus Well, technically you are right. What I was trying to say is that the statement is correct if you add "almost everywhere".

Comment: @Klaus Yes, of course, but I don't think the user doing the OP can grasp this just yet.

Comment: @JoseBrox an example for my conjecture,please

Comment: @user637244 As user1892304 has explained in his answer, your statement is true for continuous functions. As examples of common continuous functions (in some domain) you have polynomials, trigonometric functions (sin and cos), exponentials, logarithms, roots...

Comment: @JoseBrox Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is true, if you change it like that

If $\int_{a}^{b} f^2(x) = 0$ then $f(x) = 0$ a.e. (a.e. = almost everywhere).

And the opposite direction holds as well ...   $\ddot\smile$